# Should class-specific "constants" still be declared at module level?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

In [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it's stated that "Constants are usually defined on a module level […]".  This makes sense for the standard library, where constants tend to pertain to the entire module rather than a particular class (e.g. `zlib.MAX_WBITS` or `re.UNICODE`).  I'm currently writing a module, however, where the constants are all related to individual classes.

The module is designed to allow Python programs to work with an application-specific serialization format in which blocks of data are arranged into "chunks" and those chunks are further arranged into "regions".  The dimensions of chunks and regions are useful constants to expose, and I had been doing so as class properties until I chanced across that line in PEP 8.

I'm inclined to leave them as they are (PEP 8 *also* says "foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds", after all), but want to make sure that I won't be *too* badly breaking users' expectations by doing so.  (The module hasn't yet been released, so backwards compatibility isn't an issue.)

For reference, "PEP 8" style…

```
CHUNK_SIZE_X = 16
CHUNK_SIZE_Z = 16
REGION_SIZE_X = 32
REGION_SIZE_Z = 32

def Chunk(object):
    # magic happens here

def Region(object):
    # magic happens here
```

…and my current, "class-based" style…

```
def Chunk(object):
    SIZE_X = 16
    SIZE_Z = 16

    # magic happens here

def Region(object):
    SIZE_X = 32
    SIZE_Z = 32

    # magic happens here
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Clearly, class-based constants belong in the class.  Stick with your second example.  Remember PEP8 is not handed down from the Almighty.  It's just good ideas: tradition, reason and experience can temper the meaning of scripture.

Hungrarian_prefix_notation is needless.  That's one reason you have classes.

Comment: As I said, I was already inclined to violate the PEP.  I just wanted to make sure that doing so was going to match others' expectations.  Sounds like it will.  :-)

Comment: It isn't even a violation - there's a reason PEP 8 is sprinkled with caveat words like "usually" and "generally".

Comment: @ncoghlan: Absolutely.  That was my point in using words like "Almighty" and "scripture".

Comment: @S.Lott: I should have included an @Ben at the start of that last comment :)

Comment: @S.Lott — If I considered it "scripture", surely I wouldn't have asked in the first place?  I wouldn't have thought double-checking my assumptions warranted this level of patronization.  (Particularly considering the author of the only other answer gives me the opposite advice in a comment.)

Comment: @Ben Blank: "already inclined to violate the PEP".  How can it be "violated"?  I don't get your choice of words at all.  You can call my response patronizing, but I cannot understand how "violation" applies to PEP 8, so I can't understand "patronizing", either.  It may not really warrant much of an explanation, but you seem to be using some very heavy-handed words for an idea that's pretty light-weight.

Answer (score 0):

Who consumes the constant?  You say "I'm currently writing a module, however, where the constants are all related to individual classes."  So put the constant in the class.

Comment: The constants are being consumed within the module and are assumed to be at least occasionally useful to users of the module.

Comment: @Ben Blank: Based on your description I would put them at module level, but I have no strong feelings about it.  I don't think this is a question of right and wrong.