# Is defining a constant with a loop inside a class compliant with PEP8?

Tags: python, pep8

I would like to use a mathematical serie to define a constant inside a class. I would like to know whether this is compliant with the PEP8. Thank you in advance. Please see image below

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Copy and paste the code instead.

Comment: Look also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096025/should-class-specific-constants-still-be-declared-at-module-level)

Comment: This almost feels like an XY-problem. Why do you need such a "constant"? Constants are usually numbers or strings... What do you do with that `SIZE`?

Answer (score 0):

That looks fine but `SIZE = [2 ** i for i in range(5)]` is probably cleaner.

Comment: That also doesn't really look like an answer... Might be a comment

Comment: @HeapOverflow I'm an idiot